# laravel backpack 4 crudtrait error using permission management

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have just installed laravel 6 environment and I'm trying to to use backpack with permission management plugin.
I have followed all steps in this two webs.
https://backpackforlaravel.com/docs/4.0/installation
https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager#install

Every thing seems to install ok in console. I have added this code to User.php model

```
use Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait; 
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    use CrudTrait; // <----- this
    use HasRoles; // <------ and this
...
```

But when I try to access admin panel I get this errror.

```
Trait 'Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait' not found
```

I have searched in vendor folder and the package is not available.

Has anybody had this issue with laravel 6 and backpack 4? I have tried same steps with laravel 5.8 and backpack 3.6 and works fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The permission manager addon now supports Backpack v4 as of [this commit](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager/commit/938d00eb7d95b5f6457124fda4ab95a46a531c42)

To make it work, pull down the latest version and follow the [updated docs here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager)

Mainly, change `use Backpack\CRUD\CrudTrait;` to `use Backpack\CRUD\app\Models\Traits\CrudTrait;`